# how can I give openvpn clients access to a dns server (bind9) that is located on the same machine as the openvpn server

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, bind, openvpn

I currently have a debian server that is running an openvpn server. I also have a dns server (bind9) that I would like give allow access to by the connected openvpn clients, but I am unsure as of how to do this, I already known how to send dns options to the clients using

```
push "dhcp-option DNS x.x.x.x"
```

but I am just unsure how give the clients access to the dns server that is located on the same machine as the vpn server, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Also in case this would have anything to do with adding rules to iptables, this is my current configuration for iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Thu Oct 18 22:05:33 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3831842:462225238]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3820049:461550908]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1885011:139487044]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1883834:139415168]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 18 22:05:33 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Thu Oct 18 22:05:33 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [45799:10669929]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [45747:10335026]
:fail2ban-apache - [0:0]
:fail2ban-apache-myadmin - [0:0]
:fail2ban-apache-noscript - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh-ddos - [0:0]
:fail2ban-webserver-w00tw00t - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-myadmin
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-webserver-w00tw00t
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache-noscript
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j fail2ban-apache
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-apache -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-myadmin -s 211.154.213.122/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-apache-myadmin -s 201.170.229.96/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-apache-myadmin -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-apache-noscript -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 76.9.59.66/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 64.13.220.73/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 203.69.139.179/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 173.10.11.146/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh-ddos -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-webserver-w00tw00t -s 217.70.51.154/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-webserver-w00tw00t -s 86.35.242.58/32 -j DROP
-A fail2ban-webserver-w00tw00t -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 18 22:05:33 2012
```

also here is my openvpn server configuration

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group users
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 213.133.98.98"
push "dhcp-option DNS 213.133.99.99"
push "dhcp-option DNS 213.133.100.100"
client-to-client
```

Comment: also ipv4 forwarding is enabled

Comment: You hand out dhcp leases over VPN? How does that work?

Comment: @tink I would be using bind as a master server to hand resolve names to vpn client ip's, so I could type in user1.vpn or something of the sort, and have that automatically point to a ip that is on the vpn, so for instance user1.vpn would point to 10.8.0.6

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for posting your solution - literally saved me from going insane. I had locked down my DNS server before installing and this was indeed the root of the problem. Added 10.8.0.0/24 to the ACL and bingo! Again, thank you - most people would have gone about their business without taking the time to notify other users of their findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to tell bind9 to list on an ip address that was part of the openvpn subnet

Comment: my main problem was getting the clients in the vpn to actually communicate with the dns server in the first place, and apparently I had just needed to configure bind9 to listen to a ip that was on the vpn's subnet (10.8.0.1 was the ip that I had used), after which the clients were able to connect to it without any issues. pretty much answered my own question, just took some digging around to find out what was going on :)

Comment: could be nice to share a more complete answer on in which file and which line. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding into my `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` **the subnet of the `openvpn` in this case**, my LAN is `192.168.0.xxx` and openvpn is `10.8.0.xxx`

```
listen-on port 53 { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.8.0.0/24; };
allow-query { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.8.0.0/24; };
```

added to my openvpn server config file `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` in my case 192.168.0.124 is the **DNS Server address**:

```
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN mySpecificDomain.local" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.124"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

my **complete** `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` file is

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
                192.168.0.1;
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };  

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        //dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        listen-on port 53 { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.8.0.0/24; };
        allow-query { localhost; 192.168.0.0/24; 10.8.0.0/24; };
        recursion yes;
};
```